# Is there a way with a new logcat implementation to filter out the values by string?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

After a new logcat presentation I found it nice, however, I don't see an option to filter out the values by a custom string.

for example, I can set such an argument in the query line: `package:mine level:error`  and my log will be filtered out properly, however, if I need to filter out the result log by my custom string value, there is no such an option. I mean you can click `Ctrl + F` and find something specific in the result (filtered out log), however, what am I asking is not to find the specific line in the log, I need to filter out the log by my custom string, so only relevant values left in the logcat.

P.S. This was available in the previous logcat version.

**EDIT**

Thanks for @F.G. this comment is really close, however, in case I need to filter out my log by two words it doesn't work

Eg:

```
        Log.e("HERE", "message is: onConfigurationChanged 1")
        Log.e("HERE", "message is: onConfigurationChanged 2")
        Log.e("HERE", "message is: onConfigurationChanged 3")
        Log.e("HERE", "message is: onConfigurationChanged 4")
```

my query looks like this

```
level:error message:"message is"
```

and the result is an empty logcat.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure if thats what you want, but you can filter by message as well: `package:mine level:debug tag:TestTag message:MyText`. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#searching)

Comment: @F.G. thanks your comment is really close, however, it doesn't cover all the cases, I edited my question, please take a look

Comment: Can you try `package:mine message:message is:` just without the quotation marks?

Comment: @F.G. yes, it works the same way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next to "package:mine" you just need to type what you want for filter. You don't need to type "message". For example:

```
package:mine WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_SHOW
```

When I typed:

```
Log.e("HERE", "onCreate: ")
Log.e("HERE", "onCreate: ")
Log.e("HERE", "onCreate: ")
Log.e("HERE", "onCreate: ")
Log.e("HERE", "onCreate: ")
```

I got:
[image: This]